# Spring - Attribute 'name' is not allowed to appear in element 'constructor-arg'

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am using hsqldb as a db in my program. I want to inject the constructor values over spring.

Here is my bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="ConnectionManager" class="at.tuwien.group2.vpm.persistence.ConnectionManager"
        scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:vpmDatabasetest" />
        <constructor-arg name="user" value="sa" />
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

My Constructor looks like that:

```
public ConnectionManager(String url, String user, String password) {
    if(url == null || user == null || password == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Paramaeter cannot be null!");
    }
    this.url = url;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
}
```

However, when I want to execute the code I get:

Attribute 'name' is not allowed to appear in element 'constructor-arg'

Attribute 'name' is not allowed to appear in element 'constructor-arg'

What should I use instead?

Comment: In fact it should be working without issues. I'm currently looking at similar example in our project. Which version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are using Sping 2.x. Use the **index** attribute to specify explicitly the index of constructor arguments：

```
   <bean id="ConnectionManager" ...>
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:vpmDatabasetest" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="sa" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="" />
    </bean>
```

Moreover, as of **Spring 3.0** you can also use the constructor parameter name for value disambiguation.

Comment: See Spring Documentation: [Constructor argument resolution](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-resolution)

Answer (score 11):

I had same problem using Spring 3.1.2 libraries.
My mistake was that I used old schema location.
When I changed from

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd"
```

to

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd"
```

it worked fine to use named instead of indexed constructor-args.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the name attribute

```
<bean id="ConnectionManager" class="at.tuwien.group2.vpm.persistence.ConnectionManager"
        scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:vpmDatabasetest" />
        <constructor-arg value="sa" />
        <constructor-arg value="" />
    </bean>
```

it will work. And get the latest Spring version, you seem to be using a very old one. Also, I would suggest http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ as the primary source of information about Spring.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, try to add the newer spring-beans dependency. I fix this issue by updating the jar dependency without updating the xsd version.